# Cannot Implicitly convert type IQueryable to IOrderedQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
var log = string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter?.search) 
 ? _appLog.Get().OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
 : _appLog.Get().Where(p => p.ProcessName == filter.Search).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);

log = Pagination(log.AsQueryable(), filter, "Date", "LogList");
```

The error is at the Pagination, when log.AsQueryable() try to convert from IOrderedQueryable to IQueryable

> Cannot Implicitly convert type IQueryable to IOrderedQueryable

Someone know how i can do this with an alternative way ?

Comment: Could you post the *exact* error message? I suspect it included type arguments. It would also be good to show *exactly* where, rather than just "here".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that `Pagination()` returns `IQueryable<T>`, but you are assigning the result back to `log` which is `IOrderedQueryable<T>` (since both parts of the conditional operation are ordered). Fortunately, it looks like you aren't using the ordered part, so you can presumably just *change `log`* om the first time to be explicitly just `IQueryable<T>` rather than `var` (which is picking up `IOrderedQueryable<T>`):

```
IQueryable<whatever> log = ...
```

Alternatively, just use a different variable for the result:

```
var query = ...
var log = Pagination(query, filter, "Date", "LogList");
```

Comment: @Servy read it again please; you are mistaken. The fact that `IOrderedQueryable<T> inherits from IQueryable<T>` is irrelevant for the two assignments to `log`

Comment: If the problem is what you're *guessing* it is, that wouldn't produce the error message stated.  If the error is that the `IQueryable` can't be converted to an `IOrderedQueryable` then *that* is what the error would say; it says the opposite.

Comment: @Servy yeah, since that isn't a copy/paste error message, I'm going to assume that there is some scope for human error when re-typing it; what I've posted here *would* be entirely consistent with the code shown, and would have a very similar error message, is the point. In fact, that's the **only** place that could possibly raise an error like this in the code shown - the `AsQueryable()` rules out the argument usage, and both sides of the conditional will have the same result (at least assuming standard LINQ operators)

Comment: And if you made different assumptions it could be any number of *other* problems.  You should know better than to just make a bunch of guesses about what the OP's actual situation is when an unclear question is posted, rather than working to clarify the question so that it can be given an objectively correct answer.

Comment: @Servy thanks for the lecture, but I am happy with my inference in this case, and I stand by my answer; sometimes you can't sensibly decode a question without clarification, but I *strongly suspect* that in this case : we can